# Find tag for text in confluence HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, confluence

I am trying to scrape the body of a Confluence page using Beautiful Soup.
When using the Confluence API I get the following body back (this is only a part of it):

```
<ac:layout>
    <ac:layout-section ac:type=\"two_equal\">
        <ac:layout-cell>
            <p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p>
            <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"info\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"
                ac:macro-id=\"3fbdeddd-563d-4584-b665-a2116defc645\">
                <ac:rich-text-body>
                    <p>System Status: <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"
                            ac:macro-id=\"1cb65333-dc9a-45f0-948b-fb1d1f5403e8\">
                            <ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Green</ac:parameter>
                            <ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">IN OPERATION</ac:parameter>
                            <ac:parameter ac:name=\"\" />
                        </ac:structured-macro>
                    </p>
                </ac:rich-text-body>
            </ac:structured-macro>
            <p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p>
        </ac:layout-cell>
        <ac:layout-cell>
            <p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p>
            <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"info\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"
                ac:macro-id=\"b7d32741-c5c2-4d84-b7f3-fb3f391080ab\">
                <ac:rich-text-body>
                    <p>Page Status: <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"
                            ac:macro-id=\"c947d571-9ac5-4199-a527-57fd0c8e6170\">
                            <ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Green</ac:parameter>
                            <ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">IN OPERATION</ac:parameter>
                            <ac:parameter ac:name=\"\" />
                        </ac:structured-macro>
                    </p>
                </ac:rich-text-body>
            </ac:structured-macro>
            <p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p>
        </ac:layout-cell>
    </ac:layout-section>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the system status which can be found in the paragraph 'System Status:' and there in

```
<ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">IN OPERATION</ac:parameter>
```

So my idea was to search for the paragraph with the text 'System Status: '

`paragraph = soup.find('p', text=re.compile('.*System Status.*'))`

If I have got the paragraph I can search for the tag 'ac.parameter' with the attribute 'ac:name' and thus get the System State.
`paragraph.find('ac:parameter', {'ac:name': 'title'}).text`

The second part works - I have tried this by looping through all paragraphs.
Unfortunately the first part does not work. When I use the give code I get an empty result.

I already searched my ass off but somehow it seems that I don't get the point how to search for a paragraph with a certain text.

Another thing that I recognized and don't understand:
when I search for all paragraphs using:
`paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')`
I find the paragraph but it has all text of all the subelements in it, so the paragraph.text looks like this:
'System Status: GreenIN OPERATION'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xml parser and pass in `parameter[name="title"]`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 

xml = '''<ac:layout>
    <ac:layout-section ac:type=\"two_equal\">
        <ac:layout-cell>
            <p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p>
            <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"info\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"
                ac:macro-id=\"3fbdeddd-563d-4584-b665-a2116defc645\">
                <ac:rich-text-body>
                    <p>System Status: <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"
                            ac:macro-id=\"1cb65333-dc9a-45f0-948b-fb1d1f5403e8\">
                            <ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Green</ac:parameter>
                            <ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">IN OPERATION</ac:parameter>
                            <ac:parameter ac:name=\"\" />
                        </ac:structured-macro>
                    </p>
                </ac:rich-text-body>
            </ac:structured-macro>
            <p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p>
        </ac:layout-cell>
        <ac:layout-cell>
            <p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p>
            <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"info\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"
                ac:macro-id=\"b7d32741-c5c2-4d84-b7f3-fb3f391080ab\">
                <ac:rich-text-body>
                    <p>Page Status: <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"
                            ac:macro-id=\"c947d571-9ac5-4199-a527-57fd0c8e6170\">
                            <ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Green</ac:parameter>
                            <ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">IN OPERATION</ac:parameter>
                            <ac:parameter ac:name=\"\" />
                        </ac:structured-macro>
                    </p>
                </ac:rich-text-body>
            </ac:structured-macro>
            <p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p>
        </ac:layout-cell>
    </ac:layout-section>
</ac:layout>'''

soup = bs(xml, 'xml')
print([i.text for i in soup.select('parameter[name="title"]')])
```

Only the one for system status

```
print(soup.select_one('p:contains("System Status:") parameter[name="title"]').text)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reaction. But that would deliver in my example both titles - the one under 'System Status:' and the one under 'Page Status:'.
I only want to have the one under 'System Status:'

Otherwise my solution woule already work:
`soup.find_all('ac:parameter', {'ac:name': 'title'}).text`

If I could rely on 'System Status:' beeing the first appearance (which I am not sure about) I could even use only find instead of find_all and would be done...

Comment: Thank you - that works perfectly...
I am still struggeling to understand why this works but now I have a hint and can work on it.

Comment: It is xml so I am using an xml parser to handle the name spaces. Then the parameter part with contains ensures I get the right system status parent node, the space between _p:contains("System Status:") parameter[name="title"]_ is a child combinator that goes for the child tag with attribute name whose value is title. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: Thank you very much - the part with the "space between ... is a child combinator" was my missing information! Now it all makes sense!
Thank you very much - you helped me improve that script a lot (I had an intermediate solution with a for loop going through all the pargraphs search for the right text).